# Communication between 2 firefox extensions

Tags: javascript, firefox-addon

I am developing a Firefox extension and I would like to know if it is possible to call an event from another extension.

What I want to do is use a functionality from the Firefox Extension "MultiFox". It allows the user to open a new window with new session settings, meaning he can have two different sessions of the same site opened at the same time.

I had no problem finding the function in the Multifox source code, what I would like to know is if it is possible to call this function with my extension. I'm not very skilled in Javascript and I didn't find a way to do it...

I hope I was clear enough. Does anybody know how to do this?

Comment: Possible: yes. Should you do it: no. What if a new version of Multifox is released and this function is no longer there or (worse) does something different? If you need code from Multifox then copy it into your extension (can be used under MPL 1.1 or GPL 2.0 license).

Comment: yes, I guess you have a point. I could try to prevent Multifox from updating, so I wouldn't have to fully understand the Multifox code... I'll see what I can do. Thanks anyway!